# Why bool variable can not be set to 0, in addition to the direct assignment of 0?

Tags: c++

I can not overflow the bool variable becomes zero. The variables of type bool is 1 byte long，so I consider it will overflow when variables are stored 256，but it's not like I expected.

```
#include<iostream>


int main()
{
    bool b = 0;
    std::cout << sizeof(b) << std::endl; // the result is 1 byte
    std::cout << b << std::endl; // the result is 0


    b = 256;
    std::cout << b << std::endl; // the result is 1,rather than the desired zero

    return 0;
}
```

**Maybe I did not make it clear that when only 1 byte,both 0 and 256 are stored as 00000000(binary)**

Comment: The least addressable unit on modern computers is the byte, which explains why `sizeof(bool)` is 1. But as R. Martinho Fernandes points out it only needs one bit.

Comment: Necessary for C compatibility: `if(256) { printf("not false");}` still has to work.

Comment: 256 occupy 2 byte,instead of 1 byte.

Comment: @coco: Depends on the compiler, but anyway: I used the same number as your example.

Answer (score 8):

The rule for converting numeric types to `bool` is simple: zero becomes `false`, all other values become `true`. The size and layout of the either type is irrelevant.

If you want it in Standardese:

> C++11 4.12: A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to `false`;
>   any other value is converted to `true`.

Answer (score 3):

A `bool` may use one byte in your platform, but its value representation has only one 1 bit, because there are only two values of type `bool`: `true` and `false`. Not 0, not 1, not 256.

This is mentioned in section 3.9.1 of the C++ standard, paragraph 6:

> Values of type `bool` are either `true` or `false`. (...)

You can assign 0 and 256 to a variable of type `bool` because there is an implicit conversion between `int` and `bool`. That conversion converts zero to `false` and anything else to `true`. That's what you're seeing here.

This is specified in section 4.12:

> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to
>   member type can be converted to a prvalue of type `bool`. A zero value,
>   null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to
>   `false`; any other value is converted to `true`. (...)

`b = 256` *is not storing `256`*. It's storing `true`. You cannot store `256` in a `bool` variable because `256` is not a `bool` value. This is C++ **not some form of assembly**. `b = 256` does not mean "write the lower 8 bits of 256 into the memory location referred to by variable `b`". As the standard quotes above show, it means "if 256 is zero, assign `false` to the variable `b`; otherwise assign `true`".

In common implementations the value `false` is represented as 00000000 in binary, but there is nothing preventing that. An implementation is free to choose different object representations as appropriate, because that's irrelevant: C++ code cannot see it without subverting the type system and wondering into implementation-defined behaviour. An implementation can be perfectly valid and pick 0xDEADBABE and 0xDEADD00D as the object representations of `true` and `false`: only one bit carries the value representation. The thing that matters is that `bool` is a type meant to represent simple truth values. It's not "a bunch of bits that we can test against zero".

Answer (score 1):

Converting to `bool` any numeric value other than `0` yields `1`/`true`.

Even though `sizeof(bool) == 1`, it's semantics are different from that of `char`.

Answer (score 1):

Becase the C++ standard says something like (too lazy to dig out the exact quote now) "assigning a numeric value to a bool variable, a value of zero is converted to false, any other value is converted to true".

Answer (score 0):

Probably 256 is not directly assigned but checked if it is 0. If so, the boolean will be false (0), otherwise it will be true (!= 0).

Answer (score 0):

That is how bool type works, it can be zero or non-zero

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
*reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&b) = 256;
```

It is, nonetheless, unsafe (`sizeof(bool)` can be 1 or 4 or anything else, depending on implementation).

Comment: This is unsafe because it has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I'm fairly certain **this** is defined; all memory can be aliased by an `unsigned char*` (necessary for `memcpy()` to work, C compatibility). Subsequent attempts to read it are another matter.

Answer (score 0):

bool is a system defined type and can accept only true/false or alternately 1/0. The fact that it occupies one byte is because of the restrictions placed by the present storage mechanisms: It is not possible to address data of less than one byte in the present scenario.

To make it simple to understand: think of bool as a system defined type that has an overridden assignment operator. The operator internally converts any assignment to 1/0 and hence, no overflow.